# Xcode 8 generates NSManagedObjectSubclass+CoreDataClass. What is that?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

As the title says. It also does not compile without errors.

[image: CoreDataClass extension.]

Comment: You can put your custom methods into PWTag+CoreDataClass without them getting overridden when you re-generate them from your model.

Comment: Ok. But I did that in PWTag.[hm] without them getting overridden before. Now Xcode does not even generate PWTag.[hm].

Comment: @tungsten Totally agree with you. I am having the same problem. Also its showing errors that "PWTag.h" not found..

Comment: I _think_ I solved it by changing the codegen property in the xcdatamodel to "Category/Extension" and removing the autogenerated files. This way you can keep "PWTag.h" and the categories will autogenerate on build and not cause a problem. If you are using testing. Don't forget to add your xcdatamodel in "Compile Sources" under "Build Phases"